# Azure Pipelines Matrix variables

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, yaml, azure-pipelines

Can somebody explain me how I can access the variable `build` from this matrix job setup?

```
parameters:
  # job ---
  ...
  configurations: [Release, Debug]
  ...

jobs:
  - job: nightly
    displayName: Nightly
    strategy:
      matrix:
        ${{ each configuration in parameters.configurations }}:
          ${{ configuration }}:
            build: ${{ configuration }} # !PARAMETER/VARIABLE FOR JOB SET HERE!
            ${{ if ne(configuration, 'Release') }}:
              dependsOn: Release
    pool:
      vmImage: ${{ parameters.image }}
    timeoutInMinutes: ${{ parameters.timeoutInMinutes }}
    steps:
      - powershell: Write-Host ${{ parameters.build }}
        displayName: 'Write Configuration: ${{ parameters.build }}'
```

The jobs powershell task is showing `Write Configuration:` so the variable is null?

Comment: What is this variable? where he configured?

Comment: In the matrix iteration, build (parameter?) is set and later in the powershell step used? I'm not sure how I can use anything from the matrix? Actually this yaml doesn't compile but when I use ${{ parameters.build }} it's also empty.

Comment: Ok, now I understand, check my answer :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can access the variable like every regular variable:

```
$(build)
```

So in your pipeline:

```
- powershell: Write-Host $(build)
```

Comment: Yes, just figured it out myself that I was using the `${{ parameter }}` syntax instead of the `$(variable)` syntax!

Comment: Is there any way to use that in expressions? I'm interested in `$[ upper(variable) ]` and I can't figure out any appropriate syntax for it.